# How to convert date to Unix timestamp using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to convert date to Unix timestamp using Perl. I just started learning Perl.

Date is stored in `2/25/2014` form.

I tried using `str2time()`

Comment: Please show your code using `str2time`.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module. It has been a core module for many years now and shouldn't need installing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

print Time::Piece->strptime('2/25/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')->epoch;
```

**output**

```
1393286400
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) to convert your time into a format that you can use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Time::Piece;

my $time_stamp = Time::Piece->strptime('2/25/2014', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Now, `$time_stamp` contains a *structure* of my time. I can use it to do things such as this:

```
say "The year is " . $time_stamp->year;
say "This month is called " . $time_stamp->fullmonth;
say "It is month number " . $time_stamp->month . " of the year";
```

You can also add and subtract these times together to find such things as 30 days from today by using [Time::Seconds](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) with `Time::Piece`.

Comment: Erm, so you're agreeing with me yeah?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see your answer. I sometimes type in an answer, but not submit it immediately.